# Equal height columns only work on Chrome

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I have 3 columns that extend to equal height. The problem is that they only seem to work on Google Chrome and don't work on Safari or FF at least. They also don't work on Chrome or Safari for iPad.

**See them in action [here](http://www.dssselect.co.uk/test/index.html)**

The funny thing is that on this **[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/AU5G3/)** I've prepared with exactly the same code (only changed the border for better visualisation) they seem to work on every browser.

Is there a way to fix this? Many thanks!

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="content"> <img src="http://www.gayot.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/crystals-300x160.jpg">
              <h3>Classics - Rnb - Reggae - Rare Groove - Revival</h3>
              <!-- CUSTOM LIST -->
              <div class="custom-list info-box-inner-list">
                <ul>
                  <li>Tuesday 31st December 2013</li>
                  <li>The 4* Holiday Inn Hotel</li>
                  <li>London WC1N 1HT,</li>
                  <li>pop, dance, disco, electronic</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <!-- END CUSTOM LIST -->
              <p>Quisque quis orci neque.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conetur adipiscing elit. Quisque quis orci neque.LAST WORD</p>
              <div class="btn-align-bottom"> <a href="#" class="button moreinfo">More Info...</a> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="content"> <img src="http://www.gayot.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/crystals-300x160.jpg">
              <h3>Classics - Rnb - Reggae - Rare Groove - Revival</h3>
              <!-- CUSTOM LIST -->
              <div class="custom-list info-box-inner-list">
                <ul>
                  <li>Tuesday 31st December 2013</li>
                  <li>The 4* Holiday Inn Hotel</li>
                  <li>London WC1N 1HT,</li>
                  <li>pop, dance, disco, electronic</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <!-- END CUSTOM LIST -->
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conetur adipiscing elit. Quisque quis orci neque.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conetur adipiscing elit. Quisque quis orci neque..Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conetur adipiscing elit. Quisque quis orci neque.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conetur adipiscing elit. Quisque quis orci neque..</p>
              <div class="btn-align-bottom"> <a href="#" class="button moreinfo">More Info...</a> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="content"> <img src="http://www.gayot.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/crystals-300x160.jpg">
              <h3>Classics - Rnb - Reggae - Rare Groove - Revival</h3>
              <!-- CUSTOM LIST -->
              <div class="custom-list info-box-inner-list">
                <ul>
                  <li>Tuesday 31st December 2013</li>
                  <li>The 4* Holiday Inn Hotel</li>
                  <li>London WC1N 1HT,</li>
                  <li>pop, dance, disco, electronic</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <!-- END CUSTOM LIST -->
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conetur adipiscing elit. Quisque quis orci neque.</p>
              <div class="btn-align-bottom"> <a href="#" class="button moreinfo">More Info...</a> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content > img {
    vertical-align:top;
}
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    display:table;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#wrapper > .col {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 30.3%;
    margin: 0 15px 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
#wrapper > .col > .content {
    padding:0 0 35px;
    height:100%;
}
.content {
    margin-bottom:30px;
    position: relative;
}
.content > p {
    vertical-align:top;
}
.content h3 {
    font-size:1.375rem;
    font-weight:400;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 25px 27px 0;
}
.content p {
    text-align:left;
    padding: 0 27px 30px;
}
.button.moreinfo {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
    padding-right: 0.3rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 0.3rem;
    background-color: #2a2a2a;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    color: #f39c12;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
}
div.btn-align-bottom {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:50px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.info-box {
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.info-box img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.info-box-inner {
    background: #FFF;
    padding:25px 27px 35px;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:none;
    min-height:270px;
    text-align:center;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.3);
    z-index:1;
}
.info-box-inner p {
    text-align:left;
}
.info-box-inner h3 {
    font-size:1.375rem;
    font-weight:400;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you use `absolute` `position` and because parent seems to have no `relative` position, `bottom:0;` can turn out to be `bottom` of `html` or closest parent that has a `position` like : `relative, absolute or fixed`.

Beside , Firefox do not handle `table` `display` and `position : relative;` together.

So the fix, would be unfortunately, to wrap your wrapper (displayed as table) inside a wrapper that can receive : `position:relative;`  wich will extend with .wrapper and give you a bottom area reachable by coordonates.

Your fiddle updated : http://jsfiddle.net/AU5G3/1/

Notice dropping left and right coordonates in CSS wich are calculated from main wrapper and not the col area .

Comment: So I basically wrapped everything on a a div with the class .mainwrapper and and give it a position:relative; but it didn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: is your test online ?

Comment: okay, i updated your fiddle and set a main container in relative position and remove this position to .content wich was actually the container catching the bottom coordonates.

Comment: Thanks. Is it the same link?

Comment: On your Fiddle is fine but on if you check my example here it isn't http://www.dssselect.co.uk/test/index.html

Comment: rules are overwritten by your CSS . it puts col on float, wich totally kills any display value, so you loose the display:table-cell (.row div.col {} or .large-12 columns div.col or a mixed of these pre established rules) remove these classes from HTML or overwrite them